# How to continue testing in TestFlight after stopping

Tags: ios, testflight

- I installed an app via testflight.
- Once done with it, I clicked *Stop Testing*
- It disappeared from my list
- I now want to test again. I've tried redeeming the code and it just tells me I've already opted in.

I just need to know how to undo the *Stop Testing* action.

Comment: you can't, you have to be reinvited by the developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove user from itunesconnect.apple.com and add / invite again. There is no direct way for a user to undo in case accidentally stopped testing from within Testflight app.

Answer (score 2):

open [itunes connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and login with your apple developer account credentials, then select you application from `My Apps` -> `TestFlight` -> `All Testers` or `iTunes connect users` -> click `Resend Invite` or `Invite` beside `emailid` which you are using in your device(iphone or ipad) in which you have stopped the testing!

After sending invitation, open your mail id and accept it and you will continue the testing!